# PHP Web scraping tutorial is failing

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to wrap my mind around some PHP web scraping using cURL. I recently picked up a short book on the topic, but am stuck on one of the tutorials and can't seem to find where the error is. The cookie.txt file is created, so I know that at least one portion of the function is executing properly.

I've tried using both the id and name attributes of the name and password `input` fields without any luck. As far as I can tell, I'm also using the correct POST url.

```
<?php 

// Function to submit form using cURL POST method
function curlPost($postUrl, $postFields, $successString) {

  $useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3'; // Setting using agent of a very old, yet popular browser.

  $cookie = 'cookie.txt'; //Setting a cookie file to store cookie

  $ch = curl_init(); // Intializing cURL session

  // Setting cURL options
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // Prevent cURL from verifying SSL certificate
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE); // Script should fail silently on error
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE); // Use cookies
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); // Follow Location: headers
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Reutrning transfer as a string
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); // Setting cookiefile
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); // Setting cookiejar
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); // Setting useragent
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl); // Setting URL to POST

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); // Setting method as POST
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postFields)); // Setting POST fields as array

  $results = curl_exec($ch); // Executing cURL session
  curl_close($ch); // Closing cURL session

  // Checking if login was successful by checking existence of string
  if (strpos($results, $successString)) {
    return $results;
  } else {
    return FALSE;
  } 
}

$userEmail = 'email@example.com'; // Setting your email address for site login
$userPass = 'password'; // Setting your password for site login

$postUrl = 'https://www.packtpub.com/'; // Setting URL to POST to

// Setting form input fields as 'name' => 'value'
$postFields = array (
'name' => $userEmail,
'password' => $userPass,
'form_id' => 'packt-login-form-header'
);

$successString = 'You are logged in as';

$loggedIn = curlPost($postUrl, $postFields, $successString); // Executing curlPost login and storing results page in $loggedIn

?>
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`/`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options must be set with absolute path value. `"cookie.txt"` is a relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the script under Linux and it works as expected, with two minimal corrections:

First as hindmost mentioned, the path for the coockie-file has to be absolute. You can either provide the full path or use something like this:

```
$cookie = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt';
```

OR

```
$cookie = __DIR__.'/cookie.txt'; // if PHP Version > 5.3.0
```

This will insert the directory dynamically from the path of your file in which the function is declared.

Second you have to do “something” with the content of the $loggedIn variable to see any effect and for further debugging. You could for example use this code at the end of your script:

```
var_dump($loggedIn);
```

This will echo “bool(false)” on ERROR or the content of the request as in the variable $results from that function.

Comment: Thanks theafh. I made your suggested changes and ended up with bool(false), so I'll need to explore to find where the error is.